# Why is it useful to get the diagonal of two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I wanted to ask you why is it useful to get the diagonal of two vectors? E.g.: My vectors are (2,4) and (3,1); this means that the diagonal is (5,5). But why do I have to get it? Is it that useful?

[image: https://www4d.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP1012ea60167fc11c8800003g9e0172fdg0377i?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=19]

Thank you.

Comment: That “diagnonal” vector is actually your net, or resultant, vector.

Comment: The operation defined this way turns the set of vectors into a group. Having a natural group structure on a set is often extremely helpful

Comment: @Ivan C. What you call the diagonal is actually the "resultant vector" of the sum of two vectors. Maybe this is an interesting link? https://www.mathwarehouse.com/vectors/resultant-vector.php